# How to sort text by numeric order in ruby table

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm trying to sort this text with Ruby but it does not work.

```
1,fgff
12,seffdd
2,dssffs
```

Using:

```
cat sorting  | ruby -ne 'BEGIN{ $x=[]}; $x << $_.chomp.to_s; END { puts $x.sort }'
```

I get this result:

```
1,fgff
12,seffdd
2,dssffs
```

I expected this

```
1,fgff
2,dssffs
12,seffdd
```

How woudld I fix my code?

Comment: Learn to use Ruby in a script, then try using it on the command-line. It's the easier path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're not sorting numerically, you are sorting by character values:

```
[1, 12, 2].sort # => [1, 2, 12]
%w[1 12 2].sort # => ["1", "12", "2"]
```

Instead:

```
str = <<EOT
1,fgff
12,seffdd
2,dssffs
EOT

str.lines.sort_by { |l| l.to_i }.join
# => "1,fgff\n" +
#    "2,dssffs\n" +
#    "12,seffdd\n"
```

`to_i` will return the integer value of the string, up to the first non-digit:

```
'1'.to_i # => 1
'1 2'.to_i # => 1
'1,2'.to_i # => 1
'1_2'.to_i # => 12
```

The final one succeeds, because Ruby, like many other languages, allows the use of underscore (`_`) as a separator, similar to how we use comma:

```
1000 # => 1000
1_000 # => 1000
```

Knowing that:

```
'1,fgff'.to_i # => 1
'12,seffdd'.to_i # => 12
'2,dssffs'.to_i # => 2
```

It'd also be useful to read about the difference between `sort` and `sort_by`. There are major speedups available using the proper one, given the right programming situation.

Comment: You're welcome, but don't use comments to say thank you. Mmmkay?

Answer (score 1):

If there may be duplicates of the numeric part of the string, and the rest of the string is to be used to break ties, you can do the following.

```
str =<<END
1,fgff
12,seffdd
12,seffda
2,dssffs
END

str.lines.sort_by do |s|
  n, t = s.split(',')
  [n.to_i, t]
end
  #=> ["1,fgff\n", "2,dssffs\n", "12,seffda\n", "12,seffdd\n"]
```

See [Array#<=>](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how arrays are ordered.